# In late-18th and 19th century America, how common were lawyers in criminal trials?

Tags: united-states, law

Before a slew of cases in the 20th century (*Powell v. Alabama*, *Johnson v. Zerbst*, *Gideon v. Wainwright*), there was no right to a public defendant in criminal trials. How often were defendants able to afford private defense lawyers, and how often did they take this option if available? Did poor people simply have to defend themselves? If so, did they stand any real chance of success?